# SurfaceView's scaling inconsistent work

Tags: android, scale, surfaceview

I have a problem with SurfaceView scaling.

I use SurfaceView as MediaPlayer's renderer and want to make different video zoom modes by scaling surfaceView:

```
switch(zoomMode) {
    case 0:
        surfaceView.setScaleX(1);
        surfaceView.setScaleY(1);
        break;
    case 1:
        surfaceView.setScaleX(16f / 12f);
        surfaceView.setScaleY(16f / 12f);
        break;
    case 2:
        surfaceView.setScaleX(12f / 16f);
        surfaceView.setScaleY(12f / 16f);
        break;
    case 3:
        surfaceView.setScaleX(1);
        surfaceView.setScaleY(12f / 16f);
        break;
    case 4:
        surfaceView.setScaleX(12f / 16f);
        surfaceView.setScaleY(1);
        break;
}
```

But video is rather moves (1, 2 cases) and became cropped (3, 4 cases) than scales.
In rare cases (don't know what it depends on) it works ok.

When I use TextureView instead of SurfaceView then scaling works. But with TextureView video playing not smooth (jagged) and not antialiased.

How can I make it work correctly? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

SurfaceView has two parts, the Surface and the View.  The `setScale()` methods scale the View part, but the media player is sending content to the Surface part.  Because the View is just a transparent window, you're affecting the position and frame size without affecting the pixels.  TextureView is the right answer here.

You may need to use a non-integral scale factor (i.e. `setScaleX(1.001)`) to inspire TextureView to use a texture rendering method other than unfiltered nearest-pixel.  See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474260/antialiasing-in-textureview).

Answer (score 0):

Add a transparent view above the surfaceview like relative layout and add scalegesture detector on that transparent view and when scaling occurs just perform that scaling on surfaceview.

Lets suppose that transparent view is named videoview.

```
Videoview.setOnClicklistner();
```

And when scaling is performed implement that scalefactor to surfaceview like
Surfaceview.setscaleX(scalefactor);
Surfaceview.setscaleY(scalefactor);

It will work smoothly

Comment: actually not working...